# C++ Passing array into function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I'm relatively new to C++ and am having a tough time passing my array into a separate function. Apologies for re-asking a question that has no doubt been answered a dozen times before, but I couldn't find any questions similar to the problem I have with my code.

```
int main()
{
    Array<int> intarray(10);
    int grow_size = 0;

    intarray[0] = 42;
    intarray[1] = 12;
    intarray[9] = 88;

    intarray.Resize(intarray.Size()+2);
    intarray.Insert(10, 6);

    addToArray(intarray);

    int i = intarray[0];

    for (i=0;i<intarray.Size();i++) 
    cout<<i<<'\t'<<intarray[i]<<endl;

    Sleep(5000);
}

void addToArray(Array<int> intarray)
{
    int newValue;
    int newIndex;

    cout<<"What do you want to add to the array?"<<endl;
    cin >> newValue;
    cout<<"At what point should this value be added?"<<endl;
    cin >> newIndex;

    intarray.Insert(newValue, newIndex);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You need to provide the `Array::Insert` implementation if you want someone to help you.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin  It is new in C++11 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/

Comment: @stonemetal That's `std::array`, not `Array` as used in this program.

Comment: Ahh, I shouldn't have deleted my comment, then.  So what is this mysterious `Array`?

Comment: @bames53 I was thinking it was just a combination of left off using namespace std and includes + capitalization typo, but you are right std::array doesn't have an Insert method.

Comment: @stonemetal it's std::array in C++. Also I don't see an `Insert` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a *copy* of the array, so any changes will not affect the original.  Pass by reference instead:

```
void addToArray(Array<int> &intarray)
//                         ^
```

Comment: That's not his only problem though.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Care to elaborate?

Comment: He declared an object but he's using it as an array: `Array<int> intarray(10)`. That should be `Array<int> intarray[10]`

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not sure that's true; the constructor could be `Array::Array(size_t size)`, which seems reasonable.  Without seeing `Array.h` though, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem I was having. I also realized that I had forgotten to declare the function. It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of a more general question on **parameters passing**.

You may want to consider the following guidelines:

1. If you want to pass something to a function to *modify* it inside the function (and make the changes visible to the caller), *pass by reference* (**`&`**).

   e.g.

   ```
   // 'a' and 'b' are modified inside function's body,
   // and the modifications should be visible to the caller.
   //
   //     ---> Pass 'a' and 'b' by reference (&) 
   //
   void Swap(int& a, int& b)
   {
       int temp = a;
       a = b;
       b = temp;
   }
   ```
2. If you want to pass something that is *cheap to copy* (e.g. an `int`, a `double`, etc.) to a function to *observe* it inside the function, you can simply *pass by value*.

   e.g.

   ```
   // 'side' is an input parameter, "observed" by the function.
   // Moreover, it's cheap to copy, so pass by value. 
   //
   inline double AreaOfSquare(double side)
   {
       return side*side;
   }
   ```
3. If you want to pass something that is *not cheap to copy* (e.g. a `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.) to a function to *observe* it inside the function (without modifying it), you can *pass by const reference* (**`const &`**).

   e.g.

   ```
   // 'data' is an input parameter, "observed" by the function.
   // It is in general not cheap to copy (the vector can store
   // hundreds or thousands of values), so pass by const reference.
   //
   double AverageOfValues(const std::vector<double> & data)
   {
       if (data.empty())
           throw std::invalid_argument("Data vector is empty.");

       double sum = data[0];
       for (size_t i = 1; i < data.size(); ++i)
           sum += data[i];

       return sum / data.size();
   }
   ```
4. In modern C++11/14 there is also an additional rule (related to *move semantics*): if you want to pass something that is *cheap to move* and make a *local copy* of it, then **pass by value and `std::move` from the value**.

   e.g.

   ```
   // 'std::vector' is cheap to move, and the function needs a local copy of it.
   // So: pass by value, and std::move from the value.
   //
   std::vector<double> Negate(std::vector<double> v)
   {
       std::vector<double> result( std::move(v) );
       for (auto & x : result)
           x *= -1;
       return result;
   }
   ```

---

Since in your `addToArray()` function you modify the `Array<int>` argument, and you want *modifications visible to the caller*, you can apply rule #1, and *pass by reference* (`&`):

```
void addToArray(Array<int> & intarray)
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is use pointer, as usual declare the function

```
void yourFunction(int * arrayPointer);
```

In `main()` function you should input

```
int yourArray[8] = {11, -2, 45, 37, 18, 35};
int * arrayPointer = &yourFunction[0];
yourFunction(yourArray); // call your function
```

Finally in `yourFunction()`

```
void yourFunction(int * arrayPointer)
{
    // print all number in the array
    for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        cout << *arrayPointer << " ";
        arrayPointer++;
    }
}
```

This at least work for me, hope this will help